# Does there exist other integer models that contain an exponential number of branches thats not knapsack for the branch-and-bound method?

Tags: integer-programming

During a class assignment, I was presented with the following question:

```
Provide an integer program that has an exponential number of branches...(expunged excess)
```

There was more to the question, but I'm primarily concerned and curious about finding more integer programs than I the ones I found that fit this criterion. A few models I came up with are:

$$\min z = x_{n+1}$$
Subject to:
$$2x_1 + 2x_2 + \cdots + 2x_n + x_{n+1} = n$$
$$x_n\in\{0,1\}\forall n$$

when $n$ is odd, and

$$\max z = x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n$$
Subject to:
$$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n \le n-\frac{1}{2},\exists n\in\mathbb{R}^+$$
$$x_n\in\{0,1\}\forall n$$

Both of these are [single-constraint knapsack problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

I mentioned this problem to one of my peers, who said it reminded him of the [Klee-Minty Cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klee%E2%80%93Minty_cube). Therefore, I'm wondering/asking if more model types are not a single-constraint knapsack that proves that the branch-and-bound algorithm will take exponential steps, and if there isn't why?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [Karp's 21 NP-complete problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karp%27s_21_NP-complete_problems).